# Proof or counter example: Hilbert space

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Prove or disprove the following statement:

Let H be a Hilbert space and M a closed subspace of H. For any $h \in H$ there exists some $w \in M$ such that $h - w \in M^{\perp}$ (the orthogonal complement).

My own attempt at a counter example (I believe it to be false since M is not linear):

Consider the hilbert space $H = \mathcal{L}_{[0,1]}^2({\mu})$  (that is, the functions on [0,1] with integrable second moment wrt. Lebesgue measure).

I then define $M := \{1_{[0,1]} \}$ and consider $h := x \in H$ and $w := 1_{[0,1]}$ Then we have:

$\langle h-w,w \rangle = \langle h,w \rangle - \langle w,w \rangle = \int_{[0,1]}x d\mu - \int_{[0,1]}1d\mu = -\frac{1}{2} $

Which shows that $h - w \notin M^{\perp}$, but is this correct?

Comment: Your counterexample doesn't work; you would have to show that for $h:=x$, there is **no** possible $w$ within the span of $1_{[0,1]}$.  In any case, what is your definition of the orthogonal complement?

Comment: The answer to this will be that the statement **is** true because $H = M \oplus M^\perp$ for any closed subspace $M$.

Comment: I see. Any suggestions? The orthogonal complement is defined (in my book) as $M^{\perp} = \{ h \in H: \langle h, w \rangle = 0 \text{ for all w } \in M \}$.

Comment: The usual approach is to use the fact that $M$ is a closed convex subset of $H$, so there exists a (unique) point $w \in M$ which is closest to $h$.

Comment: But is it always true that $M$ is convex if it is a subset of a Hilbert space? How about linearity?

Comment: $M$ is not just a sub**set**: it's a sub**space**.  Of course it's convex; it's closed under any linear combinations, which include convex combinations.

Comment: Of course - I have definitely misinterpreted subspace. It makes alot more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you start looking for counterexamples consider that every closed subspace $M\subseteq H$ has an orthogonal complement $N\subseteq H$, which means that every vector $h\in H$ has a decomposition $h=m+n$ where $m\in M$ and $n\in N$, solving your problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement#Properties_2